# C# EF Code First foreign key doesn't work

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-code-first

My Entity Framework code-first approach creates the following two tables which should be connected my a navigation property:

```sql
-- TABLE CustomColumnData
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[CustomColumnData]
(
    [ObjID] [char](42) NOT NULL,
    [CustomColumnID] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [Value] [nvarchar](max) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_CustomColumnData] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ObjID] ASC, [CustomColumnID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- TABLE PickLineMapper
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PickLineMapper]
(
    [LeadingObjID] [char](42) NOT NULL,
    [PickingListNumber] [int] NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_PickLineMapper] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([LeadingObjID] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- FOREIGN KEY
ALTER TABLE [CustomColumnData]
    ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_CustomColumnData_PickLineMapper_ObjID]
        FOREIGN KEY ([ObjID]) REFERENCES [PickLineMapper] ([LeadingObjID])
            ON DELETE CASCADE;
```

This code fails with an error code:

> Error 547 |
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_CustomColumnData_PickLineMapper_ObjID". The conflict occurred in database "MPA", table "dbo.PickLineMapper", column 'LeadingObjID'.

The code for creating the foreign key constraint is the following:

```cs
private void InitializeForeignKeys(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<PickLineMapper>()
        .HasMany(plm => plm.CustomColumnData)
        .WithOne(ccd => ccd.PickLineMapper)
        .HasForeignKey(ccd => ccd.ObjID);
}
```

Here's one of the two classes. From there, I want to be able to access all elements from the `CustomColumnData` table where `PickLineMapper.LeadingObjID` is equal to `CustomColumnData.ObjID`, no matter what the `CustomColumnData.CustomColumnID` is. You have to know, that `CustomColumnData` must have a compound primary key consisting of `ObjID` and `CustomColumnID`.

```cs
public class PickLineMapper
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1, TypeName = "char(42)")]
    public string LeadingObjID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public int PickingListNumber { get; set; }

    public ICollection<CustomColumnData> CustomColumnData { get; set; }

    public bool IsCommissioned => Convert.ToBoolean(
        this.CustomColumnData
            .Where(ccd => ccd.CustomColumnID == MpaContext.CustomFieldID_Commissioned)
            .SingleOrDefault());
}
```

How can I correctly define a working navigation property between those two tables?

Comment: There is a mapping file that exists that associates the database tables/columns with the c# classes.  You need to refresh the mapping after changing the database.  You can do it through VS menus.   Try update model wizard : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/data-tools/entity-data-model-tools-in-visual-studio?force_isolation=true&view=vs-2022

Comment: @jdweng I'm using the code-first approach. You're talking about database first.

Comment: You still have to get the mapping correct.  It is easy to update database first and the let the tools update the c# code.  You are doing it the hard way.